# Как выбрать таблицу с определенным текстом? PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Как выбрать только таблицу с определенным текстом? PHP, MySQL
Например.. "Драма" в genre таблице**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как выбрать только таблицу с определенным текстом? PHP, MySQL
Например.. "Драма" в genre таблице**

Comment: `$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM singles WHERE genre  like '%?%'"); $sth->execute(['Драма']);` Но `like '%%'` негативно влияет на производительность, поэтому жанры лучше делать через отдельную таблицу

Comment: @InDevX, спасибо!